# Crash on creating pipeline state - "the parameter is incorrect" - HRESULT 0x80070057

Tags: sharpdx, directx12

All input appears valid, although the DirectX12.ShaderByteCode() pointer is null - I don't know if that's indicative of anything; the buffer does contain data.

Edit: Diagnostic hub output:

```
Profiling of 'Graphics Frame Capture' started.
Graphics Frame Capture has exited.
Profiling of 'Graphics Frame Capture' stopped.
```

Edit2: Debug output:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' in SharpDX.Direct3D12
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in SharpDX.Direct3D12
External component has thrown an exception.
```

Code:

```
var pipelineStateDesc =
    new GraphicsPipelineStateDescription
    {
        BlendState =
            BlendStateDescription.Default(),
        DepthStencilFormat = SharpDX.DXGI.Format.D32_Float,
        DepthStencilState =
            new DepthStencilStateDescription
            {
                IsDepthEnabled = false,
                IsStencilEnabled = false
            },
        Flags = PipelineStateFlags.None,
        InputLayout = inputLayout,
        PixelShader =
            new ShaderBytecode(pShader),
        PrimitiveTopologyType =
            PrimitiveTopologyType.Triangle,
        RasterizerState =
            RasterizerStateDescription
            .Default(),
        RenderTargetCount = 1,
        RootSignature = rootSignature,
        SampleDescription =
            new SharpDX.DXGI.SampleDescription(1, 0),
        StreamOutput =
            new StreamOutputDescription(),
        SampleMask = int.MaxValue,
        VertexShader =
            new ShaderBytecode(vShader)
    };

pipelineStateDesc.RenderTargetFormats[0] =
    SharpDX.DXGI.Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm;

// Crash happens here.
// Pointer-to-implementation.
// .GetDevice returns the SharpDX.Direct3D12.Device.
pipelineState =
    graphicsDevice
        .ImplAs<GraphicsDeviceInternal.GraphicsDeviceImpl>()
        .GetDevice.CreateGraphicsPipelineState(
            pipelineStateDesc
            );
```

Comment: Enable the debug device and look for diagnostic output.

Comment: Sorry, insomnia. Using the debug device, CreateDevice crashed with "Invalid parameter". Using "CheckFeatureSupport()" with debug off returned false and a max feature level of 12.1, so I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: Ignore previous message; I had "break on" set for info and message. Updating with diagnostic hub output on CreateGraphicsPipelineState.